# How can i make my index data array to be multiple depends on their TIME IN and Event Time Started

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

sorry if my title is really misleading, i still don't know how to call my problem,

so i have a set of array

```
0: {name: "Bob", time_in: "18:00:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "yes"}
1: {name: "Dino", time_in: "19:05:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "yes"}
2: {name: "Anna", time_in: "19:05:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "no"}
3: {name: "Tina", time_in: "19:00:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "N/A"}
4: {name: "Aiza", time_in: "18:00:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "N/A"}

length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

how can i make bob to be x10 if he's time is early before the event start.

so it will be like this

```
0: {name: "Bob", time_in: "18:00:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "yes"}
1: {name: "Bob", time_in: "18:00:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "yes"}
2: {name: "Bob", time_in: "18:00:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "yes"}
3: {name: "Bob", time_in: "18:00:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "yes"}
4: {name: "Bob", time_in: "18:00:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "yes"}
5: {name: "Bob", time_in: "18:00:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "yes"}
6: {name: "Bob", time_in: "18:00:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "yes"}
7: {name: "Bob", time_in: "18:00:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "yes"}
8: {name: "Bob", time_in: "18:00:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "yes"}
9: {name: "Bob", time_in: "18:00:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "yes"}
10: {name: "Dino", time_in: "19:05:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "yes"}
11: {name: "Anna", time_in: "19:05:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "no"}
12: {name: "Tina", time_in: "19:00:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "N/A"}
13: {name: "Aiza", time_in: "18:00:00", event_start: "19:00:00", attendance_status: "N/A"}
```

their entry will depend on their time_in and the event_start

here is the other rules

```
TIME_IN          TIME_START     attendance_ status        
 6:00              7:00                 yes        = 10 tickets (EARLY + YES)
 7:05              7:00                 yes        = 5 tickets (LATE + YES)
 7:05              7:00                 no         = 3 tickets (LATE OR EARLY + NO)
 7:00              7:00                 N/A        = 1 tickets (LATE + N/A)
 6:00              7:00                 N/A        = 1 tickets(EARLY + N/A)
```

i am trying to do this in javascript but i still have no idea how can i make the index to be multiple.
any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an array of objects. To access any one of them you can do the following.

```
// CHANGE THE ARRAY NUMBER TO ANY IN THE ARRAY YOU WANT TO ACCESS
array[0].time_in; // OR
array[0].name;
```

Then by extrapolating from that we can then...

```
// DECLARE YOUR ARRAY, AND ANOTHER HOLDING ARRAY
var people = // YOUR ARRAY HERE
var holding = [];

// MAKE A LOOP FOR THE ARRAY
people.forEach(function(item){
    // CREATE AN IF LOOP TO CHECK YOUR CONDITION
    if(item.time_in < item.event_start) {
        for(var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
            holding.push(item);
        }
    } else {
        holding.push(item);
    }
});

// PLACE OVERWRITE THE FIRST ARRAY WITH YOUR HOLDING
people = holding;
```

Your homework then is to try and apply your 'rules' to this logic.